Mutiple Distinct Record Count from TWO tables having different value need to be matched and reported if there is a difference
I want to compare the count of DELIQUENCY_COUNT=0 with the count of CYCLE_DELIQUENCY = A and Count of DELIQUENCY_COUNT=1 with count of CYCLE_DELIQUENCY = B and so on.
If the count is different a mismatch must be reported
DELIQUENCY_COUNT 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  TABLE 1 
CYCLE_DELIQUENCY A B C D E F G H I J  TABLE 2 

Attribute Name = DELIQUENCY_COUNT, Value = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, Table Name = Table1
Attribute Name = CYCLE_DELIQUENCY, Value = A B C D E F G H I J, Table Name = Table2

EQUVALENT VALUES (A=0, B=1, C=2, D=3, E=4, F=5, G=6, H=7, I=8, J=9)
Here, I am expecting
If the Table1, DELIQUENCY_COUNT for value 0 is 1000, and Table2, CYCLE_DELIQUENCY for value A is 1001, Then we have to report it.
Similarly, for next value
Table1, DELIQUENCY_COUNT for value 1 is 5000, and Table2, CYCLE_DELIQUENCY for value A is 5000, Then we don't have to report it.
Table1 and Table2 equivalent Value attribute wise
EQUVALENT VALUES (A=0, B=1, C=2, D=3, E=4, F=5, G=6, H=7, I=8, J=9)
I have written a SQL but not sure if it will work
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(CYCLE_DELIQUENCY)
 CASE  
    WHEN 'A' THEN 
        COUNT(CYCLE_DELIQUENCY)
        MINUS
        SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DELIQUENCY_COUNT) FROM {}.{} 
        WHERE  DELIQUENCY_COUNT = 0
    END ' A REPORT ',
    WHEN 'B' THEN 
        COUNT(CYCLE_DELIQUENCY)
        MINUS
        SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DELIQUENCY_COUNT) FROM {}.{} 
        WHERE DELIQUENCY_COUNT = 1
    END ' B REPORT ',               
FROM {}.{};


What RDBMS are you using?

Are the values you show different columns in the same row? Or different rows?

Not sure if it will work? Well when you tried it, did it work?

I strongly recommend showing your source data and desired results as tables, not as sequences. Read [mre] and Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, even for a very simple SQL query? for more details.

Using Oracle (code should be adjusted to your rdbms):
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table tbl_1 AS 
Select LEVEL - 1 as deliquency_count, LEVEL * 10 as count_value 
  Connect By LEVEL <= 10;
 
Create Table tbl_2 AS
Select 'A' as cycle_deliquency, 10 as cycle_count_value Union All
Select 'B', 20 Union All
Select 'C', 31 Union All
Select 'D', 40 Union All
Select 'E', 50 Union All
Select 'F', 60 Union All
Select 'G', 72 Union All
Select 'H', 81 Union All
Select 'I', 90 Union All
Select 'J', 99

... you could create a cte to link the data from your tables ...
WITH
  cycle_links AS
    ( Select cycle_deliquency, cycle_count_value,
             Row_Number() Over(Order By cycle_deliquency) - 1 as deliquency_count
      From   tbl_2
    )

... use join to get the data and case expression to flag the rows to be reported ...
--      S Q L : 
Select     t.deliquency_count, t.count_value, 
           l.cycle_deliquency, l.cycle_count_value,
           Case When t.count_value != l.cycle_count_value 
                Then Concat('REPORT ', l.cycle_deliquency)
           End as REPORT
From       tbl_1 t
Inner Join cycle_links l ON(l.deliquency_count = t.deliquency_count)
Order By   t.deliquency_count

R e s u l t :



DELIQUENCY_COUNT
COUNT_VALUE
CYCLE_DELIQUENCY
CYCLE_COUNT_VALUE
REPORT




0
10
A
10
null


1
20
B
20
null


2
30
C
31
REPORT C


3
40
D
40
null


4
50
E
50
null


5
60
F
60
null


6
70
G
72
REPORT G


7
80
H
81
REPORT H


8
90
I
90
null


9
100
J
99
REPORT J



... if you need the data transposed into a row - with Oracle you can Pivot the result - otherwise use Case expressions for conditional aggregation ...
--      S Q L    (Pivot) : 
SELECT Max(a) as a, Max(b) as b, Max(c) as c, Max(d) as d, Max(e) as e,  
       Max(f) as f, Max(g) as g, Max(h) as h, Max(i) as i, Max(j) as j
FROM    ( --  this is the above   S Q L   code
          Select     t.deliquency_count, t.count_value, 
                     l.cycle_deliquency, l.cycle_count_value,
                     Case When t.count_value != l.cycle_count_value 
                         Then Concat('REPORT ', l.cycle_deliquency)
                      End as REPORT
          From       tbl_1 t
          Inner Join cycle_links l ON(l.deliquency_count = t.deliquency_count)
          Order By   t.deliquency_count
        )
PIVOT   ( Max(REPORT) 
           For CYCLE_DELIQUENCY In('A' as a, 'B' as b, 'C' as c, 'D' as d, 'E' as e, 
                                   'F' as f, 'G' as g, 'H' as h, 'I' as i, 'J' as j)
        )

R e s u l t :



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J




null
null
REPORT C
null
null
null
REPORT G
REPORT H
null
REPORT J



fiddle
